# How to open own program from an url (link)?

Tags: vb.net

I want to be able to send an email with a link in it like ... myprogram:customerid?1423 ... or something like that. So when the user click the link, it must open "myprogram" and lookup the customer with ID 1423.

How can I create custom urls/links in windows?

Thanks!

Comment: You have to register a _protocol handler_ for your custom protocol. For example, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914.aspx