# Mobile Web - Add to Calendar Feature

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

How to implement the add to calendar in mobile web ? Is there any way to implement this. This feature is to be supported for all smart phones.

Comment: What do you mean by "Add to calendar"? Be more specific, explain what technologies are you using, your objectives and http://www.whathaveyoutried.com.

Comment: We need to add an event to calendar for mobile web. How should we implement this in mobile web.

Comment: Do you need to implement a date picker or a real calendar implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately calendar specified by **`HTML5`** spec is still not properly implemented among different **`HTML5`** so you will need to use a 3rd party implementation.

### Datepickers

If you need them for your **`jQuery Mobile`** site (looking into your question history) you can always use a 3rd party date picker's for **`jQuery Mobile`**. 3 are available and they are great. Unfortunately only **`Mobiscroll`** can be used cross platform because of its support for different skins. This is also a datepicker I would advise you to use if you are using **`jQuery Mobile`**.

**[Mobiscroll](http://mobiscroll.com/)** - http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/WDjfR/

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){       
    $('#demo').mobiscroll().date({
        invalid: { daysOfWeek: [0, 6], daysOfMonth: ['5/1', '12/24', '12/25'] },
        theme: 'android-ics',
        display: 'inline',
        mode: 'scroller',
        dateOrder: 'dd mm yy',
        dateFormat : "dd-mm-yy"
    });  
});
```

**[Mobipick](http://mobipick.sustainablepace.net/)** - http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/zyVjE/

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){       
    $('#demo').mobipick({
        dateFormat: "MM-dd-yyyy"
    });
});
```

**[Datebox](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox2/)** - http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/ktbcP/

```
<input name="mydate" id="mydate" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "datebox", "useNewStyle":true, "dateFormat": "mm/dd/YYYY"}'/>
```

More working examples can be found in this blog **[article](http://www.gajotres.net/10-life-saving-jquery-mobile-plugins/)**.

### Calendars

But if you want a real calendar implementation there one I have used, probably there are more but this one is responsive enough. While not create for **`jQuery Mobile`** specifically it will work just fine. Even if creating a normal site this plugin is a real monster.

**[FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/)** - http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/ZSd2C/

In this example you can see how it reacts to smaller screens.

```
$(document).on('pageshow','#index',function(e,data){    
    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        editable: true,
        events: [
            {
                title: 'All Day Event',
                start: new Date(y, m, 1)
            },
            {
                title: 'Long Event',
                start: new Date(y, m, d-5),
                end: new Date(y, m, d-2)
            },
            {
                id: 999,
                title: 'Repeating Event',
                start: new Date(y, m, d-3, 16, 0),
                allDay: false
            },
            {
                id: 999,
                title: 'Repeating Event',
                start: new Date(y, m, d+4, 16, 0),
                allDay: false
            },
            {
                title: 'Meeting',
                start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
                allDay: false
            },
            {
                title: 'Lunch',
                start: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0),
                end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),
                allDay: false
            },
            {
                title: 'Birthday Party',
                start: new Date(y, m, d+1, 19, 0),
                end: new Date(y, m, d+1, 22, 30),
                allDay: false
            },
            {
                title: 'Click for Google',
                start: new Date(y, m, 28),
                end: new Date(y, m, 29),
                url: 'http://google.com/'
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="date" />
```

[New HTML5 Date input](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html)

-

To link that date to your calendar/app, you may want to [write a browser extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185882/is-there-a-browser-on-android-accepting-extensions), get the extension to attach an [On Hold event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710111/determining-long-tap-long-press-tap-hold-on-android-with-jquery) to every [Date input](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html) on each page you browse.

It could be possible to [open your calendar via URL link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482629/how-to-open-own-program-from-an-url-link). If the calendar doesn't have a protocol-handler, you could write your own calendar app and [assign it a protocol to handle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421048/android-ios-custom-uri-protocol-handling)

Comment: This only shows the date. But, how can we add an event to the phone's calendar. Say for instance, i want to add a fixture event to my phone's calendar in mobile web.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how I would go about it